# Metadata version mismatch for module after creating IOS build ( node_modules/@ionic-native/network/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 )

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3

When i am trying to create IOS build getting error like below.

Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/newuser/WebstormProjects/myproject/node_modules/@ionic-native/network/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
    at /Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23023:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at extractProgramSymbols (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
    at AotCompiler.compileAll (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:30:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:61:30)
    at Object.doCodegen (/Users/newuser/myproject/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/codegen.js:6:51)

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.16.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.11.1
npm   : 3.10.10 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Comment: Did you try to delete node_modules and run again npm install?

Comment: Yes I tried still getting same error.